# Best way of calling urls on my website

Tags: urls, names

I have a website where factories are stored in different categories, but now i was wondering how to call the factories in my urls.

I have an url for showing factories in a category:

```
http://mydomain.com/factories
```

I also have a page where all my factories from the database are displayed
i don't know how to call that url. the url can not be the same so i need something that works for everybody.

i tried something like:

```
http://mydomain.com/allfactories
```

but i think it looks stupid.

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quite common pattern for showing all of something is to extend the category with a filter, which in your case would be something like:

```
http://mydomain.com/factories/all
```

That way you can use the filter in your URL to select factories in let's say Europe:

```
http://mydomain.com/factories/europe
```

And moving down the list to a single factory, such as:

```
http://mydomain.com/factories/my-industry
```

You'll have a flat structure on your filter and need only to implement your taxonomy on each factory correct.

Answer (score 2):

Even though [this presentation](http://symfony.com/video/26/designing-http-interfaces-and-restful-web-services/English) is about REST, it talks a lot about URLs, (from 16min to 25min approx) and might interest you.

Main points that gets out of the presentation is that the URL should represent a ressource, and filters of these ressources should go in the query string. The query string is meant to be specific to the query, and filters are a direct fit for this category.

In your case, I would go with something like

```
http://mydomain.com/factories -- to retrieve all factories
http://mydomain.com/factories/{id} -- to retrieve a specific one

http://mydomain.com/factories?category={cat} -- to filter a category.
```

The reasoning behind that is that if tomorrow you want to add more filters, what will you do? Just add more slashes?

And get to something along :

```
http://mydomain.com/factories/myCategory/united-states/blep/bloop -- ???
http://mydomain.com/factories/myCategory/blep/bloop -- Oh wait now, is blep a country? This is not clear
```

This is pushed to the extreme, but it shows something that can become very problematic, because some parameters will become obligatory as you add more possibilities.
The parameters in the URL become ambiguous; we can not know which parameter is which if they are not all there and in order. But if I need to put all parameters, then the default one get in the URL and everything gets cluttered.

Comment: @Kees It might seem long (1hour), but it's a very good presentation and it is very well done. It's made by David Zülke a guy who works for Symfony Framework

Answer (score 1):

Since there are multiple categories, I would suggest using `http://mydomain.com/factories/category-X`, and `http://mydomain.com/factories/all`

Comment: yeah i think /factories/all looks nice. but i want to keep the urls as clean and short as possible. so i think this is the best way.